# Replication Data Issue

Tags: sql-server, replication, snapshot

After configuring replication all the data from tables has replicated from publisher to subscriber.  Now my requirement is whenever I insert new record in publisher only that record should replicate rather than reinitialize all the records to subscriber because my table is having millions of records.

Rather than drop and reinitialize snapshot cont we store earlier sync data of table in subscriber and only sync the new record.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Unless this is a snapshot publication, this is how replication works. Which type of publication did you set up? Merge? Transactional?

Comment: Transactional Rep

Comment: My req is even though snapshot generated, Rather than drop and creation of article (table) cont we simple add the newly inserted row to already synced article in subscriber

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. When the replication agent runs, newly added rows at the publisher are inserted at the subscribers. The snapshot is used only to initialize the subscription. What am I missing?

Comment: It will insert entire table whenever snapshot has generated, I will first time insertion next onwards only inserted rows

Comment: MIght be a language barrier, but I don't understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Publisher table -- almost 1 million records.            Subscriber -- 1 million plus whenever I insert new record into publisher generally it will drop the table in subscriber and create with 1 million plus 1 new record.. So getting latency to get the records in subscriber... I need to make old 1 million records are fixed and new record only has to insert into subscriber table...

Comment: This is not what is supposed to happen. Something is invalidating the subscription and marking it for reinitialization. Are you sure you are only inserting a new row to the article? Isn't there any DDL operation on the table, such as dropping a column?

Comment: Doesn't mean I am only inserting.. Is there any way to compare and insert mismatched rows to subscriber tables in transaction repl

Comment: It means that you're doing something that you shouldn't do. Find it and kill it.